# How to configure build number format on TeamCity when using Git source control

Tags: git, github, build, teamcity

We have recently moved from Team Foundation Server (TFS) source control to Git source control. We are using TeamCity as our build server.

Our build number format in TeamCity is defined as this:

```
%env.Release%.%env.Patch%.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%
```

This gives us a build number like this:

```
24.9.2.34561
```

But after moving to GIT our build number looks like this:

```
29.4.179.4d549289e564929454d1e783319e2c3e5b45cd71
```

Can anyone tell me how to setup TeamCity to generate build number like this when using GIT source control:

```
xx.xx.xx.xxxxxx
```

Comment: That `4d549289e564929454d1e783319e2c3e5b45cd71` is most likely the Git hash for that commit/version of the deployed code. I would recommend seeing if `build.vcs.number` can be shortened to 7 characters (the typical short has Git uses) for your purposes. Look [here for documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the short version of the Git commit hash isn't available via a [predefined build parameter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/predefined-build-parameters.html). There is a related feature request in TeamCity issue tracker though: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-22082.

From from a comment in the tracker, the current workaround is to get the necessary hash inside the build script from the passed revision and change the build number via a [service message](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/service-messages.html).